# VBA code to run macro based on whether a cell value exists within a column

Tags: excel, vba

looking a little help - relatively new to VBA and struggling with finding some VBA code to do what I am trying to do.

Basically - I have cell B3 in sheet "summary" which is an input cell. Upon entering data into that cell, I want the VBA code to check column B of worksheet AAT and if there is a match (IE any value in column B in the worksheet AAT matches cell B3 in worksheet summary) then I want Macro AAT to run.
If the data isn't found in this worksheet, the macro will search column B of Worksheet AOT and if matching data is found, macro AOT is to run.
If the value in B3 isn't found in column B of worksheet AOT or AAT, then a popup box advising that the data isn't found is to appear.

Comment: Hello, what did you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

First off, don't name macros as AAT or AOT because those are valid column names, as well as names of sheets in your workbook. At some point that will catch you out, as well as make your code confusing - I've chosen to call them "MacroAOT" and "MacroAAT"

```
   Sub ChooseMacro()
   Dim r As Range
   r = Worksheets("AAT").Columns("B").Cells.Find(Worksheets("summary").Range("b3"))
   If r Is Nothing Then
        r = Worksheets("AOT").Columns("B").Cells.Find(Worksheets("summary").Range("b3"))
        If r Is Nothing Then
             MsgBox "Not Found"
        Else
            MacroAOT
        End If
    Else
          MacroAAT
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You are a star - will test it and come back to you - Looks completely different to the code I was attempting - which is a good thing.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Say we have three macros in a standard module:

```
Sub FAIL()
    MsgBox "error"
End Sub

Sub AAT()
    MsgBox "AAT"
End Sub

Sub AOT()
    MsgBox "AOT"
End Sub
```

In cell **C3** enter:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3,AAT!B:B,0)),"AAT",IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(B3,AOT!B:B,0)),"AOT","FAIL"))
```

this formula tells the system which macro to run.  Once a value has been entered in cell **B3**, run this:

```
Sub TestB3()
    Application.Run Range("C3").Value
End Sub
```

[image]